# Amazon ECS [Fargate] - How do you restart all Tasks in a Service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

We have a task that loads some configuration from database. After the settings are updated on db we would like to be able to restart all the tasks in a service so that the settings propagate to all instances.

I used

aws ecs update-service --force-new-deployment --cluster CLUSTER_NAME --service SERVICE_NAME

But this causes downtime. As this stops and start

Answer (score 1):

Best to scale out your ECS Service, e.g. from 10 to 20 tasks, and once they're up scale down again to 10, that will kill the obsoleted ones.

Check out [ECS Rolling Updates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/deployment-type-ecs.html).

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you have not configured or don't have proper [health checks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_HealthCheck.html).
With this ECS can gracefully remove tasks from the load balancer and only add new tasks when they are ready.

Simply expose a GET that returns a HTTP 200 in your application and use ECS to [actively check](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/target-group-health-checks.html) if your task is running before sending traffic to it.

ECS will try make sure that there is a minimum healthy percent when doing a [rolling update](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/deployment-type-ecs.html).

I restart our clusters this way without downtime.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).